# cwrsync not reporting --stats flag

Tags: flags, cwrsync

When running the following cwrsync script on our SBS2003 server (backing up to a remote NAS), the results from the --stats flag tell me that no files or data were moved. But, the destination directory has been populated.

Also - where would I add a --delete flag into the options to ensure source = destination, but any deleted files are first copied to the BACKUPDIR.

<> - --stats reports results when I manually run the script.  If I schedule it, no stats are reported.

```
SET SOURCE=/cygdrive/s/
SET DEST=%SPARENAS01%::HAVOFFSITE/shared
SET BACKUPDIR=xxx_backup_xxx/%date:~10,4%/%date:~7,2%/%date:~4,2%
SET OPTS=--force --update --backup-dir=%BACKUPDIR%/Shared --exclude=xxx_archive_xxx/ --  modify-window=5 --stats -brtz

rsync %OPTS% %SOURCE% %DEST% >> %date:~10,4%.log
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to redirect stderr-output to your log file as well. Try this one:

```
rsync %OPTS% %SOURCE% %DEST% 1>>%date:~10,4%.log 2>>%date:~10,4%.log
```

Comment: OK - let me get this straight.  1>>%date:~10,4% is writing the command to the log file. 2>>%date:~10,4% is writing the --sync output?

Comment: This doesn't appear to work:  rsync %OPTS% %SOURCE% %DEST% 1>>%date:~10,4%.log 2>>%date:~10,4%.log.  rsync %OPTS% %SOURCE% %DEST% >>%date:~10,4%.log >>%date:~10,4%.log does work when run directly, but not when run as a Windows scheduled task.  Why would that be?